# How can I save changes to the context in a jQuery each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, each

I have the following code, which preprocesses some response data from an AJAX call before displaying it (the displaying part is not shown). In particular, it sets the `src` attribute of the image in each `li` element of the response.

```
$(response.items).filter('li').each(function(i){

  $('img', this).attr('src', 'images/Picture.jpg');
  if (i==0){
    console.log(this);
    console.log(response.items);
  }

});
```

The output of `console.log(this)` shows that the `src` attribute gets set correctly in the context represented by `this`, but the output of `console.log(response.items)` shows that `response.items` is unchanged.

Is there a (preferably non-hacky) way to persist all changes to the `li` elements to `response.items`?

Comment: The callback function for `.filter()` needs to return a truthy value to indicate which items should be kept or removed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you're using the `filter` method.  `Filter` (and also `map`) don't modify the original array, they essentially make a copy of it. So if you would check the return value of this whole code block like this:

```
var processed = $(response.items).filter('li').each(function(i){

  $('img', this).attr('src', 'images/Picture.jpg');
  if (i==0){
    console.log(this);
  }

});
console.log(processed);
```

It should properly show the changed values. Depending on what you want to do you could also use a `map` method after the each.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work. I resorted to a hacky solution where I just build a new list